# Select multiple options with datalist with Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Context**: I'm retrieving an array with several tickers from stocks (such as AAPL, FB, TSLA,etc) from PHP and now I'd like the user to select multiple stocks from this datalist, however, I'm not sure how to do exactly that. I've tried using `multiple`, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am being able to see the scrollable list of the 500+ tickers from PHP (connected to MySQL), but I can only choose one at a time and not several of them.

HTML and Javascript

```
<div class="loss">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div id="data">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                  <input style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);border-radius: 10px; border: none;  text-align: center;" list="brow">
                  <datalist id="brow">
                    <form id="myForm">
                      <select id="selectStock">
                        <option></option>
                      </select>
                    </form>
                  </datalist>
                  <input class="button1" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></input>
                </form>

               
                <script>
                 
                  var select = document.getElementById("selectStock");
                  var options = <?php echo json_encode($tickerArray) ?>; 

                  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = options[i]; 
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.innerHTML = opt; 
                    el.value = opt; 
                    select.appendChild(el); /
                  }


 
                </script>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Any help is very welcome!

Comment: That's not how a combination of a text input field and datalist works. The purpose of that is to have the user select _one_ value, that is then put into the text field. You could create a new textfield, once the existing one has gotten a value, and apply the datalist (maybe minus the already selected value) to that one again ... If you don't like that option, then you will have to go for something else altogether.

Comment: Or move the value from the input field somewhere else after it has been set (like, append it to a second text field), and then clear the first input field, so that the user can then make a selection from the datalist again in that field.